# float and wrap content width

Tags: css, css-float

Why if i add a width to my main content, it no more wrap arount my floated div ?

```
<div style="float:left;width:30%;">
   content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1
</div>

<div id="mainContent" style="width:30%;">
      content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ty9wuLeh/4/

Comment: If 'content 2' needs to be "around" 'content1', you'll need to place the first div inside the second. https://jsfiddle.net/ty9wuLeh/5/

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not precise enough. I know how to have 'content 2' "around" 'content1' : i just have to remove width in 'mainContent' div. But I wanted to know the reason why it works like this ? what is the algorithm to compute the display ?

Comment: Then what is the question.....................?

Comment: As to _why_ this happens: if you inspect the output you can see (in Chrome at least) that the div actually overlays the first div, I think that it's the content of the `mainContent` div that happens to rest against the content of the first div. Technically though the `mainContent` div is the full width of the page. To get what you want to achieve, you could simply `float:left` on the `mainContent` div too.

Comment: Yes i agree the second div overlays the first div. But why adding or removing the width in the main content modify the wrapping behaviour ? I know it works this way but I don't get the logical reason behind this. I mean : by specifying width on the main content, intuitively I just want to constraint the width of this div, not modifiying its wrapping behaviour.  So why this side effect ?

Answer (score 0):

Your floated `div` should be contained within your `mainContent` `div`:

```html
    <div id="mainContent">
    <div style="float:left;width:30%;">
      content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1
    </div>
      content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 
      content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 
      content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 
      content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 content2 
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ty9wuLeh/6/